# Segments in NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, dos, fasm

I had been trying to replicate an example from FASM (flat assembler) to NASM but I had not been able to do it and I try to understand the way NASM handles segments (sections).

```
ormat mz
entry main:start
stack 100h

segment main
start:
  mov ax, text
  mov ds, ax

  mov dx, hello
  call extra:write_text

  mov ax, 4c00h
  int 21h

segment text
  hello db 'Hello world!', 24h

segment extra
write_text:
  mov ah, 9
  int 21h
  retf
```

FASM generates a MSDOS exe file and loading this in DEBUG I see the following:

```
0D9D:0000 B89F0D            MOV     AX,0D9F
0D9D:0003 8ED8              MOV     DS,AX
0D9D:0005 BA0000            MOV     DX,0000
0D9D:0008 9A0000A00D        CALL    0DA0:0000
0D9D:000D B8004C            MOV     AX,4C00
0D9D:0010 CD21              INT     21
```

As you may see, FASM creates the segment and set the CALL as a far call. extra is effectively placed in a separate segment. The data segment is in a separate segment as well.

I tried doing this example in NASM:

```
section code
..start:
  mov ax, seg hello
  mov ds, ax

  mov dx, hello
  call extra:write_text

  mov ax, 4c00h
  int 21h

section data
  hello db "Hello World!", 24h

section extra
write_text:
  mov ah, 9
  int 21h
  retf

section stack class=stack
  resb 100h
```

And linking with wlink using this link file:

```
system  dos
option  map
name    seg2.exe
file    seg2.obj
```

The generated code is different:

```
0D9D:0000 B89D0D            MOV     AX,0D9D
0D9D:0003 8ED8              MOV     DS,AX
0D9D:0005 BA1200            MOV     DX,0012
0D9D:0008 9A1F009D0D        CALL    0D9D:001F
0D9D:000D B8004C            MOV     AX,4C00
0D9D:0010 CD21              INT     21
0D9D:0012 48                DEC     AX
0D9D:0013 65                GS:     (unused)
0D9D:0014 6C                INSB
0D9D:0015 6C                INSB
0D9D:0016 6F                OUTSW
0D9D:0017 20576F            AND     [BX+6F],DL
0D9D:001A 726C              JB      0088
0D9D:001C 642124            AND     FS:[SI],SP
0D9D:001F B409              MOV     AH,09
```

As you may see, write_text is in the same segment as the rest of the code (and apparently the data segment as well) but it was not put in a separate segment as I thought.

Am I missing something here? Is there any way to actually place code in a separate segment? Any help, guidance or explanation of what is happening or how to achieve such would be appreciated!

and yes, I tried in MASM and the same thing happens, is FASM the only one with that super power?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the linker just merges segments if possible.  It might be possible to supply an option that prevents this from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a support for **memory models**, which [NASM lacks](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.5), it treats intersegment transfers as NEAR and *the programmer is responsible for coding CALL FAR instructions where necessary*.

No, FASM is not the only assembler aware of memory models. Here is your program tailored for [€ASM](https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/index.htm#MODELeq)

```
|                          |seg4 PROGRAM Format=MZ,Model=LARGE,Entry=start
|[main]                    |[main] SEGMENT Purpose=CODE
|0000:                     |start:
|0000:B8{0000}             |  mov ax,PARA# [text]
|0003:8ED8                 |  mov ds, ax
|0005:BA[0000]             |  mov dx, hello
|0008:9A[0000]{0000}       |  call write_text
|000D:B8004C               |  mov ax, 4c00h
|0010:CD21                 |  int 21h
|0012:                     |
|[text]                    |[text] segment Purpose=DATA
|0000:48656C6C6F20776F726C~|  hello db 'Hello world!', 24h
|[extra]                   |[extra] segment Purpose=CODE
|0000:                     |write_text:
|0000:B409                 |  mov ah, 9
|0002:CD21                 |  int 21h
|0004:CB                   |  retf
|[stack]                   |[stack] SEGMENT Purpose=STACK
|0000:....................~|   DW 100h * BYTE
|                          | ENDPROGRAM
|        **** ListMap "seg4.exe",groups=4,segments=4,entry=[main]:00000000h,stack=[stack]:00000100h
|        [main],RVA=00000000h,size=00000012h=18,group [main]
|          [main],RVA=00000000h,size=00000012h=18,width=16,align=0010h,purpose=CODE
|        [text],RVA=00000020h,size=0000000Dh=13,group [text]
|          [text],RVA=00000020h,size=0000000Dh=13,width=16,align=0010h,purpose=DATA
|        [extra],RVA=00000030h,size=00000005h=5,group [extra]
|          [extra],RVA=00000030h,size=00000005h=5,width=16,align=0010h,purpose=CODE
|        [stack],RVA=00000040h,size=00000100h=256,group [stack]
|          [stack],RVA=00000040h,size=00000100h=256,width=16,align=0010h,purpose=STACK
```